# How can I insert gaps into serial communication?

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, qt5, timing

An old application made with Qt4 communicates with an external device via a serial port, and I would like to port it to Qt5.

To synchronize the device, a gap is inserted between data packages:

(Inside the `run()` method in a class derived from `QThread`)

```
QSerialPort *serial;

// setting up the serial port  
// ....

for (...)
{
    serial->write(data, length);
    serial->flush();
    this->msleep(pause); 
}
```

where `pause` is longer than the time needed by the writing, to guarantee a gap.

This all worked fine under Qt4, but it doesn't work on Qt5.

`serial->flush();` causes the whole communication to hang (and never recover) after the first data package, so I removed it.

The sleeping has no effect. Neither `this->msleep(pause);` nor `QThread::msleep(pause);` work, the data packages are just glued together. This is highly likely to be caused by the removal of flushing, the actual data is only sent after enough bytes are gathered in the buffer.

I guess a working solution would be to no longer use a class derived from `QThread`, but use a `QObject` with `moveToThread()`, set up a bunch of signals and slots, and use a `QTimer` for the timing.

However, this would result in rebuilding a large part of the application from scratch. Is there a better way?

Comment: You may want to have a peek at `std::thread`. It's more modern, and offers a `sleep_until` in addition to a `sleep_for`.

Comment: @MSalters : the problem seems to be with flushing the serial port, not with the waiting itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `serial->flush();` with `serial->waitForBytesWritten();` solved the problem.

It seems that some of the interactions between the serial communication and the event loop have been changed between Qt4 and Qt5.

Comment: There is no event loop involved, because you never let the event loop run. Get rid of that sleep call and drive your communications from a timer. Blocking, synchronous code is almost always a sign of thinly veiled trouble.

Comment: It is in a GUI application, so there is an event loop. And, as stated in the question, the code is within a `QThread`-derived class. That class is started as it should be, and under Qt4 everything worked perfectly. I know about the other method, I even mentioned it. But for this purpose a blocking synchronous code is exactly the code which is the clearest, simplest, and best suited for the job.

Comment: Qt event loops are thread-local objects. There isn't one in the thread where your code runs - the GUI thread is immaterial. It worked under Qt4 because you depended on poorly defined behavior of `flush()`. Blocking code is never the simplest because now you're stuck with a thread that cannot be terminated, and such a thread may well make your application crash on exit unless you're careful. You'll also enjoy yourself to no end proving that all error conditions are handled around each and every blocking call. Maintenance suffers as the calls are too easy to add. State machines trivialize this.